# Why is the result not a missing value when I do the ** operation on two pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

I created two series, s1 and s2, using pandas and numpy modules.
When I do the addition and subtraction operation on the two series, the index b,d,f, and g have missing values as expected, but when I do the ** operation, the result is b has a value of 1, while d,f, and g are still missing values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = pd.Series(np.arange(4), index=list('abcd'))
s2 = pd.Series(np.arange(2,7),index=list('acefg'))

s1
a    0
b    1
c    2
d    3
dtype: int32

s2
a    2
c    3
e    4
f    5
g    6
dtype: int32

s1 ** s2

#the result
a    0.0
b    1.0 #I expected this should be missing too
c    8.0
d    NaN
e    NaN
f    NaN
g    NaN
dtype: float64
```

My question is that is this regular for exponential operation?

Answer (score 0):

Because of 1 in every power is 1. Even if 1 ** nan. Perhaps, its an internal optimisation of numpy

Comment: Thank you! I tried 1 ** np.NaN, and the result is 1. It explains a lot.